# How does rename_sth work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example

```
rename_column :user, :email_address, :email
```

What name does it rename from and what does it rename to? There are three attributes here which completely confuse me.

Comment: user - table name, email_address - old column name, email - new column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rename_column :user, :email_address, :email
```

**:user** - table name

**:email_address** - from(old name)

**:email** - to(new name)

In one migration file(single migration) you can alert more then one table at a time, that's why passing a table name as an argument make sure that the column in a right table is going to be renamed.